# Make child view respect parent layout round corners

Tags: android, android-layout, rounded-corners

I have a layout with round corners who has a child without corners inside that can be move. When this child is in a side it doesn't respect the round corners of the parent.

So this is what I want to achieve:

[image]

And this is what I have currently:

[image]

Sorry for the bad quality in the second image but you can see here that the corners are not round because of the child.

This is the layout that I am using:

```
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/bg_pill_selector_button_switch_parent">

    <FrameLayout
        android:layout_width="@dimen/no_width"
        android:layout_height="@dimen/no_width"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <com.mb.components.widget.MBLabel
        android:id="@+id/lbFirstButtonPillSelectorSwitch"
        style="@style/MBPillSelectorButtonSwitchText"
        android:layout_width="@dimen/no_width"
        android:layout_height="@dimen/no_width"
        android:background="@drawable/bg_pill_selector_button_switch_element"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/glPillSelectorSwitch"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/gl2PillSelectorSwitch"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        tools:text="Gastos" />

    <com.mb.components.widget.MBLabel
        android:id="@+id/lbSecondButtonPillSelectorSwitch"
        style="@style/MBPillSelectorButtonSwitchText"
        android:layout_width="@dimen/no_width"
        android:layout_height="@dimen/no_width"
        android:background="@drawable/bg_pill_selector_button_switch_element"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/glPillSelectorSwitch"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/gl3PillSelectorSwitch"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/gl2PillSelectorSwitch"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        tools:text="Ingresos" />

    <com.mb.components.widget.MBLabel
        android:id="@+id/lbThirdButtonPillSelectorSwitch"
        style="@style/MBPillSelectorButtonSwitchText"
        android:layout_width="@dimen/no_width"
        android:layout_height="@dimen/no_width"
        android:background="@drawable/bg_pill_selector_button_switch_element"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/glPillSelectorSwitch"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/gl3PillSelectorSwitch"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        tools:text="Otros" />

    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.Guideline
        android:id="@+id/glPillSelectorSwitch"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        app:layout_constraintGuide_begin="@dimen/begin_guideline_pill_selector_button_switch" />

    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.Guideline
        android:id="@+id/gl2PillSelectorSwitch"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        app:layout_constraintGuide_percent="0.33" />

    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.Guideline
        android:id="@+id/gl3PillSelectorSwitch"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        app:layout_constraintGuide_percent="0.67" />

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/framePillSelectorSwitch"
        android:layout_width="@dimen/no_width"
        android:layout_height="@dimen/no_width"
        android:background="@drawable/bg_pill_selector_button_switch_selected"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/glPillSelectorSwitch"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/gl2PillSelectorSwitch"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />
</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

parent doesn't have rounded corners, any view never have rounded corners... views are always rectangle, but may have rounded corners drawable set for background

in your case your first and last item in row also should have rounded corners (both left OR both right), there is an option for such in [XML shape drawable](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/drawable-resource#Shape)

```
<shape
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shape=["rectangle" | "oval" | "line" | "ring"] >
    <corners
        android:radius="integer"
        android:topLeftRadius="integer"
        android:topRightRadius="integer"
        android:bottomLeftRadius="integer"
        android:bottomRightRadius="integer" />
```

so modify your `bg_pill_selector_button_switch_element`, make additional left and right versions (hint:don't set `radius`, its for all-in-one)

Comment: The problem is that the view that is inside the parent ´framePillSelectorSwitch´ can move from one side to the other (is the one with the red background) of the parent so it can be in the left side or the right side. Then I cannot just add a background with a radius only in one side because it can be changed to the other side.